# I want to add video noise/grain based on an audio track?

Tags: audio, noise, programming

Does anyone know of a plugin that would allow me to add video noise that is based on an audio track ?

Anything at all that would let me do this would be fantastic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert audio to keyframes. Right-click the footage with the audio, and choose **Animation>Keyframe Assistant>Convert Audio to Keyframes**, or with the audio layer selected go to the **Animation** menu in the menu bar.

[image]

This will create a new layer with keyframes for the intensity of the audio. You can copy those keyframes on to any property that you want to animate and adjust them in the graph editor, or you can use an expression on the property and select the keyframes with the expressions pickwhip. This means that the audio levels can control *any* animatable property including parameters for your favourite noise effect.

A useful trick is that you can apply EQ to the audio before you convert it to keyframes and have different sets of keyframes for the bassline and the melody sounds.

Comment: Thank you @stib!  To simplify this for anyone else reading, the detailed way to do this is:  right click on your audio and select key frame assistant, convert audio to key frames.  Find the key frames under both channels and copy and then paste them into the intensity of your grain effect.

Comment: Added a bit more detail to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Trapcode Particular is the tool of choice for this. You can generate any type of noise/particles, based on an audio track, and tie the parameters to not just the track, but specific frequencies (so the noise is warped on low bass, or changes color on high frequencies).

There are also a lot of templates you can buy on videohive that will jumpstart the process.

Comment: Heres a good example to you youtube video, and the template is downloadable in the description for free. (But you will need the Trapcode Suite).  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dSi_SD19UE